# Android does not show project files

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Android does not show project files. It only shows that it is loading.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqUAh.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried to switch to another view mode and then switch back? btw, I usually use the "Project" view for Flutter projects instead of "Android".

Comment: Today i updated my AndroidStudio to 2021.1.1, and Flutter & Dart plugin. now flutter project dosen't have the `Android` view. i assume it has been deleted from flutter projects.

Comment: Great, I switched to Project and it showed me the files normally. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to "Project" mode worked for me.